# Project for tabs using fragments not working

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments

I am trying to make tabs using fragments. At the moment on clicking each tab the content that is displayed is "Content for tab with tag: (tag) ". Here's my project:

`http://www.filedropper.com/androiduxframework_1`

I refered to many links related to tabs with fragments ( including

`http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/`

and

`http://neilgoodman.net/2012/03/12/working-with-fragments-on-android-part-2/`

) before making this project. However it's not giving the expected output. No tab is displayed on AVD and just 
one word is printed ( "People" : The indicator/tag for the 1st tab). 
Please help me. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jake Wharton's Android Sherlock Tab.It will give more idea. It will support in all

versions. Import that sherlock library and use the samples, hope you will get it.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock